# How to delete items from SQLite database through the context menu?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, contextmenu

Please help me understand. I have an app in which I add items to database, then display it on the `ListView`. Almost all works fine, but when I delete items through context menu, then the top first item is deleted. No matter which item I choose.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_menu_item:
            String itm_ps = itemView.getItemAtPosition(itemPos).toString();
            ToDoDB.deleteData(itm_ps);
            mAdapter.remove(itm_ps);
            return true;

        case R.id.quit_menu_item:
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}
```

And SQL query code:

```
public int deleteData(String value) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       delete_result = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{value});
       database.close();
    }
    return delete_result;
}

public Cursor viewData() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: Please double check your phrasing "when i delete items through context menu, that the top first item is deleted". Do you mean "when I delete items through context menu then the top first item is deleted"?

Comment: Yes. I want to delete item which i choose in listview. To remove items along from listview and from database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your sql database.

```
public void delete(String time) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{time});
        db.close();
    }
```

Also call it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_menu_item:

            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            String key = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
            db.delete(String.valueOf(key));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//  Load items to the database once more like you would do at startup of the application.
            return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Oohh, now ide show me this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  1 arguments were provided but the statement needs 0 arguments.

Comment: db.delete(String.valueOf(key)); and db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{time});

Comment: In ListView: id = 0 - First Item. id = 1 - Second item. In my database id = 7 -First item. id = 8 - Second item. Id's don't match.

Comment: Remove this line from your code and check ```mAdapter.remove(itm_ps);```